# How to show div, based on Html.DropDownList?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, drop-down-menu, show

I am using this code for DropDownList:

```
@Html.DropDownList("VlogaNaziv", ((SelectList)ViewBag.DropListVloge).Select(t => new SelectListItem() { Text = t.Text, Value = t.Text, Selected = (t.Text == ViewBag.SelectedVloga) }), Model.VlogaNaziv, new { @class = "form-control"})
```

How can I implement this code: http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/v4gNL/ to my dropdown list.

In my dropdown list I have only 3 values.

- Admin
- Spediter
- SpediterOsnovni

I want to my div is shown in chosen value 2) Spediter

Thanks for help.

Comment: on Change event of your drop down,compare the value in drop down, if it is Spediter mark you div as visible. Try this and post your code, so that we can help you if you are facing any error.

Comment: I Updated your fiddle too, to my answer below!

Comment: Where did you put fiddle?

Comment: the same fiddle of your, I just updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved , just change the div like this

```
<input type='text' class='text' id='business' value size='20' />
```

Your problem was you didn't specify and Id to the div, while your using the JQuery Id Selector!

Comment: what should I use for Value? maybe "Value = t.Text"

Comment: you can use this line to get the selected : $("#VlogaNaziv option:selected").val();

Comment: got it, I just put in js, value='Spediter' tnx man, It work, before when I try, I did not use id, and it didn't work.

Comment: pls mark it as an asnwer so others can benefit from it too!

Comment: i did, but stackowerflow timeing prevent me :), I can accept answer after 3 min, but now is time off, so I mark it :D